# Force Windows to show a system tray icon

Tags: .net, windows, .net-2.0, system-tray

This is a pretty stupid question, but here goes:

Is there a way (in .net) to force Windows to show your system tray icon instead of hiding it?  I don't want to do this all the time, but at least for the first time my application is run I would like it to be visible in the system tray.

Comment: No, it does not *need* to be visible in the system tray. That is up to the user. Don't rely on your application being visible in the system tray, because it might not be. (as JP said, in Win7, users are in full control of it).

Comment: When did I say I was relying on anything? I just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: I hope not. IMO, the system tray should be completely under user control.

Comment: +1 this is not a stupid question. You can do all sorts of nasty things to user's desktop through API, so this is not something which should be impossible IMHO. You could, for example, pop up a message and notify user that he/she is running Win7 and ask if icon should be shown always, if it is important for the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to always show program tray icons in Windows by *default*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904790/how-to-always-show-program-tray-icons-in-windows-by-default)

Comment: It REALLY bothers me how many people jump on an idea like this calling it a bad question.  Whether it is bad depends TOTALLY on how it is USED.  Yes, it is probably not good to do in a commercial program.  But if I want to tailor how MY system tray looks on MY computer ONLY, and if I want to do it in C# rather than use Windows menus, then there is no reason to see that as bad!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you taking about Windows 7?  If so, then [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904790/how-to-always-show-program-tray-icons-in-windows-by-default).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That's what I needed to know.

Comment: If the answer is no then how it is possible that Skype icon is always visible, the same goes for Miranada IM. I did not change their settings in control panel.

Comment: @Wodzu - I tested out Miranda, and it actually doesn't always show the icon (you have to wait around a minute before the icon disappears, as is the default behavior for tray icons that were recently installed). Also of note is that Windows 7 remembers your setting for previous tray items, even after uninstall - if this is your case, you might have set it to always display in a previous install.

Comment: @Maranas thanks for the testing. You are right, it was the case of settings.

Comment: i have installed f.lux on windows 7. it's icon always shows in the tray. all other apps go in the 'show hidden icons'. see https://imgur.com/a/B2OlLZU . how does flux do this ?

Answer (score 9):

As Raymond Chen would say, "Imagine if this were possible." Now tell me how many apps would choose *not* to force their tray icon to be always visible! Everybody thinks their tray icon is the most important. If there was a programmatic way to say "show my tray icon all the time", we'd be back to Windows 95.

Configuration of tray-icon hiding is left to the user, on purpose. If you want to always see your tray icon on your computer, there's nothing stopping you. Just right-click on the expander button, click "Customize Notification Icons" (that's what it's called in Vista, may vary in other OS versions), find your app's tray icon in the list, and select "Show".

Answer (score 3):

it does not show because, even if you uninstall your application, the display setting is saved under the PastIconsStream registry entry. Windows saves the settings for icon identifiers even if the app isn't already installed. For the first install, it will appear, then hide itself (which is what you want to achieve, I think). For subsequent installs, it won't appear anymore, because Windows remembers the setting. If you are still testing your application, try clearing the PastIconsStream registry entry. This will revert back to the "show at first, then hide" behavior.

Comment: Ahhh... that explains what I was experiencing before.  I thought maybe there was something different with my installation a while ago because I have noticed the "show at first, then hide" on other machines since then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first time your tray icon is shown, it will be made visible, at least for a short time. The rest is left up to the user - if they want to hide it then you should really respect that decision.

Comment: I have every intention of respecting the user's intentions.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: then there is nothing to do, it'll show on the first use

Comment: Unfortunately, that has not been the case in my testing.  Maybe it's an anomaly, but I believe Windows is hiding my icon right off the bat.  This will be confusing to some users.  Just wanted to see if there was a way to go "Look at me.  I'm down here!" right after installation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force it to be visible (as noted above, and rightly so), however if you show a balloon notification (like Windows Live Messenger does when you first try to close the window), your icon will appear while the balloon is visible.  You could also use this to draw attention to your app to say "look at me, I'm down here!".

Please, for the sake of your users, make it only do this once, at most, though!

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I may or may not try this approach.  Even used once, I think the idea would be annoying to the user.  Whatever I do, I promise to code responsibly.  I hate programs that think they know what's best for me, too ;-)