# windows7 set the "show icon and notification" programmatically

Tags: c#, scripting, windows-7, vbscript

I want my application (written in c#) which needs to run on Windows 7 and show an icon in the notification area. The  default is "only show notification" I my icon to be shown by default. looking for the api in c# or to wite a script for this.
If there's no direct way to do this is there any overriding way?

Comment: Just to understand this right. You want to override the user's decision on when and how your notification or messages are being shown? Don't do that. The user will hate you for ignoring his settings. If you meant something else, it won't hurt to do into more detail.

Comment: I don't want to override user's desicion but at the design of my program the user should see the icon all the time at the bottom. I know that whoever installed my program WANTS to see the icon so it is much easeier for the user that it'll be automatically than if he needs to set it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically forcing icons to be visible in the "notification area" /"systray") in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259299/programatically-forcing-icons-to-be-visible-in-the-notification-area-systray)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is by design the Windows 7 doesnt let you do this programmatically.

Could you not do something on the main TaskBar using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)?

Comment: +1 for both mentioning that you can't do that and that the Windows API Code Pack would be the way to go for anything you _can_ do.

Comment: +1 too.  If you want to shove your application in the users face, the defined way to do this is to put your app in the taskbar.