# How to make NotifyIcon to Always Show and will not be hide by Windows itself

Tags: c#, vb.net

I try using Icon.Visible = True. But it will only show icon in the taskbar for a brief period of time before Windows will hide it automatically. How to programmatically make show icon permanently?

The effect is the same as doing it manually, by click on task bar icon button -> Customize Notifications and set behavior to  = "Always Show / Always Hide / Hide when inactive" for each taskbar icon on the list.

How to set it to “Always Show” programmatically? thanks

Comment: Make your program *really* useful, it is automatic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to always show program tray icons in Windows by *default*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904790/how-to-always-show-program-tray-icons-in-windows-by-default)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to be able to force your icon to always be visible.  The kind of thing you're trying to do (hey, my program is very important, always show its icon!) is why they have the notification area set to hide icons by default.  If this were possible, it would defeat the whole purpose of "hide by default" as every driver manufacturer out there would take advantage of it and we'd be no better off than the days of Windows 98 when half of users' task bar's were nothing but icons.

Comment: Or you could make sure that the program is always active. Probably not what its users would want either though :-)

Comment: I have a program call Clipmate that is able to do just that. it give you an option to show System Tray Icon = "Always Show" or "If icon is not active". but don't know how it does it.