# Registry setting to make icon always show in the Windows 7 tray

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, registry, system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to always show program tray icons in Windows by *default*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904790/how-to-always-show-program-tray-icons-in-windows-by-default)

I thought setting a tray icon to always show it in the "new" system tray on Windows 7 (or Windows 8) was impossible from a non-Microsoft program or a script... until I stumbled upon Dropbox's desktop agent (downloadable right off their home page) that somehow manages to keep its tray icon on the system tray fully visible for as long as it needs. (At least during the set-up stage when it asks for your user name and password. I left it running for at least 5 or 10 min and the icon stayed.)

I then clicked the little chevron that shows a pop-up that enables users to change which icons to show and, what would you know, the dropbox's icon was set to "Show icon and notifications". Mind you, I did not change it manually... So there must be a way to do it from a program.

Any idea how it was done?

PS. Please do not point me to the MSDN document saying that it could not be done...

Comment: Just curious, how is it an "exact duplicate"? The post you quoted says, "it is impossible" and I gave you a solution below... anyway, it'd help to first read it, guys...